# Entity Data Load _in Spring Batch Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Am using Spring Boot + Spring Batch + myBatis. we have 2 entities (`DepartmentEntity`, `EmpoyeeEntity`) / `Department-mapper.xml` and `Employee-mapper.xml`

```
EmpValidationEntity.java(Employee Entity)
public class EmpValidationEntity{
private empName;
private empDept;
setter/getter 
}    

DepartmentValidationEntity.java(Department Entity)     
public class DeptValidationEntity{
private deptName;
private Dept;
setter/getter 
}

EmpMapper.xml(Employee mapper file-myBatis based)
//select query from Emp

DeptMapper.xml(Department mapper file)
//select query from Dept

EmpInterDependentFieldsValidator.java (Validator class file)

public class EmpInterDependentFieldsValidator
        implements ConstraintValidator<EmpInterDependentFieldsValidation, EmpValidationEntity> {
@Override
    public boolean isValid(SSNValidationEntity value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        Object fieldValue = null;
        boolean isValid = false;

        boolean isFieldValid = true;
        try {
            fieldValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, fieldName);
            } 
        catch(Exception e){}
    if (isFieldValid) {
            isValid = validateFields(value, context, fieldValue, fieldName, isValid);
            } else {
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(ErrorMessageConstant.INVALID_FIELD)
                    .addPropertyNode(fieldName).addConstraintViolation();
        }
}
return isValid;}



    private boolean validateFields(EmpValidationEntity value, ConstraintValidatorContext context, Object fieldToValid,
            String fieldName, boolean isValid) {
        String fieldValue = null;


        if (fieldToValid != null) {
            fieldValue = fieldToValid.toString();
        }
        if (fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("EMPLOYEE_DEPT")) {
            return EmpValidationService.validate(fieldName, fieldValue, value, context);
        }

        return isValid;
    }

}


EmpValidationService.java(validation service class)


public class EmpValidationService{
static List<String> ssnList=null;           
        public static boolean validate(String fieldName, String fieldValue, EmpValidationEntity entity, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
            boolean isValid = true;
    if(departmentList.contains(entity.getEmpdept())){
      errorMessage.append(ErrorMessageConstant.SSN_ALREADY_TIED_TO_ANOTHER_DOB);}           

}
```

In above class how to get DepartmentList (in single load/dump)?

from the above code ,i want pass two entity and get the scope of two entity object data into EmpValidationService class, after that i want store each entity data into different list because i want check one entity data contains to another entity data.

Comment: what defines an item in your case? Please share the minimal code those entities to illustrate your issue.

Comment: please consider entity as item (ie) DepartmentEntity is one item & EmployeeEntity as another item

Comment: What is the type of items that the `ItemReader` returns? Can you share the definition of your item reader?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine have provided classes in Question